# Fifa 99 and 2000 on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, gaming

Repost:

I've tried different options in terms of running FIFA 99 and 2000 on virtualbox. I've tried the following OS:

Windows 98
Windows 2000
Windows XP (32-bit)
Windows Vista (32 bit)
All of the above doesn't seem to work. I am able to install the games, but when I try to play them, an intro screen comes up and the screen goes black.  So is it my copies that doesn't work or am I missing some OS? I suppose that there is a log somewhere to see the errors.

Comment: Have you installed the Virtualbox Guest Additions to enable 3D support?

Comment: That made me proceed, but now goes black after "EA Sports"

Comment: You are not going to play this particular game within a Virtualbox VM due to VirtualBox not supporting the hardware virtualization required to do so

Comment: Can you use Hyper-V? (of course on a machine that supports it). What hardware virtualization is needed then?